# Both JWT and form auth in one SpringBoot app?

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring boot app that uses spring security.I implemented form based auth and it works well. I want the app to serve as the backend of an angular app i've built.I know about CORS but how can i add JWT auth to the existing spring boot app,is it recommended.

Comment: I can't answer "is it recommended", but there are multiple resources online that describe how you might implement JWT with Spring Security, such as https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt
The applicability of individual articles including the above depends on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend AOP concept to authenticate/validate your jwt token.

First thing you need to create a custom annotation. Named it as JWTsecured

```java
@Component
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JwtSecured {

}
```

Now You have a controller in which your api need to be JWT secured.

```java
@RestController
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping(value="/testApi")
    @JWTsecured
    public void isTestApi() {
    }

}
```

Now you have to write an aspect to validate your token...

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class JWTsecuredAspect {

@Around(value =" @within(com.JWTSecured) || @annotation(com.JWTSecured)")
    public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {  
   String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
   if(!isTokenValidated(token)){
    throw CustomException("Invalid Token.")
}
}
}
```

This is how you can use it along with auth. 
There are several other ways. 
Feel free to contact